# Change new order template

Tags: orders

how i can change output data in new order template, now i have here:

[image]

but this little not corrected, need

> John Genry
>
> Local
>
> test
>
> 95220
>
> Berlin
>
> Berlin
>
> Germany
>
> T.1597538

how i can change this? in template New Order i can see where i can change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to modify the email template's tables to your liking, but you should be able to get the details you want in the template using:

```
//This just gets the whole address in a specified format, not what you want
//{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getPostcode()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCity()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getRegion()}}
```

I'm not sure what the second "Berlin" refers to, region?